# Using Window authentication when i have two instances of Sql-server and two instances are attached to two different windows user account?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two Sql Instances with each having different window authentication user.So when i am using the connection string which uses local data source like

```
    <connectionStrings> 
<add name="DataContext" 
   connectionString="data source=.;
   initial catalog=northwind;persist security info=True; 
   Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

I am getting  unable to intialize database error at the beginning . Is there any way to solve this error other than deleting one instance. I can specify the data-source =local/. only .

Comment: This connection string connects to one of the instances, the default one. Is the instance running? What is the actual error that you receive? Opening a connection to the default (or any) instance doesn't return any initialization errors. Have you perhaps installed SQL Server twice using the *same* instance name?

Answer (score 0):

Two instances cannot use same endpoint. Each SQL Server has to communicate / transfer data in a different endpoint (port). Default instance uses 1433, the other instance would have been configured to other port number. You should use that port number in your connection detail. Otherwise you cannot successfully login to the named instance remotely. You should use the SQL Instance Name in the following format

```
`[Machine Name]/[Instance Name],[portNumber]`
```